# Error while running a powershell script using Psexec

Tags: powershell, batch-file, psexec

I am running the below batch file to connect the remote machine & run a powershell script on the remote machine using psexec.

**Running batch file on local machine (myscript.bat)**
Running Command: myscript.bat \\mymachine

```
set machinename=%1

@echo " started"
PsExec.exe %machinename% -u myID -p myPwd -i -d cmd /c mkdir C:\test

xcopy  DirChk.ps1 %machinename%\C$\test

psexec.exe %machinename% -u myID -p myPwd cmd.exe /c 'echo .|powershell.exe -file C:\Test\DirChk.ps1'

@echo "Completed"
```

Error:

> Starting PsExec service on \\mymachine ...Processing -File
>   'C:\Test\DirChk.ps1'' failed because the file does not have a '.ps1'
>   extension. Specify a valid PowerShell script file name, and then try
>   again.

Comment: Can you use PowerShell remoting instead of `psexec`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try double quotes. Batch files are interpreted by **cmd**, which doesn't understand single quotes. This should work:

```
psexec.exe %machinename% -u myID -p myPwd cmd.exe /c "echo .|powershell.exe -file C:\Test\DirChk.ps1"
```